# de base de datos a select JQUERY

Tags: jquery

tengo la siguiente base de datos:

[image: Mi base de datos "Razas"]

Donde almaceno lasrazas de animales en las cuales `id_especie` es la especie (canino,felino,gato,etc).

y tengo un formulario con 2 select

```
<select id="especie">
<option value="1">Canino</option>
<option value="2">Felino</option>
</select>

<select id="razas">
<option value="1">Raza canino 1</option>
<option value="2">Raza canino 2</option>
</select>
```

Lo que yo deseo es que al cambiar #especie, me filtre solo las entradas que tengan id_especie=1 (si seleccionan especie 1) y reemplaze los option de #razas

Lo que intente:

1. detectar el change de #especie y hacer una peticion php en la cual consulta a mi base de datos y me retorne solo los id_especie=... pero esto es un consumo innecesario de recursos.
2. Intente hacer un concat mysql y mostrar las entradas en un formato "json":

   ```
   $sc_razas = $bd->query("SELECT 
   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{id:',id_raza,',text:',raza,'}') SEPARATOR ',') AS 
   razas_gen,id_especie FROM razas GROUP BY id_especie");

   while ($raza = $sc_razas->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "var especie_".$raza["id_especie"]." = [".$raza["razas_gen"]."];\n";
   }
   ```

Si alguien tuviera la respuesta se lo agradeceria bastante.

Nota:
Uso este evento para detectar el cambio de especie

```
$("#especie").on("change",function() {

});
```

Comment: Leyendo lo que dices en tu punto `1`, y considerando que es un dato mínimo (el ID de la especie), podrías tener ese valor precargado en cada `option` (junto al `value` o en un atributo `data-`, y usar ese valor para hacer el filtro.

Comment: te entendi algo pero podrias porfavor explicar un poco mas tu idea, se te agradece el interes